# Manejar evento click en toda el área de un control de usuario en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He creado un control de usuario que hereda de un Panel al que le he añadido una imagen y una etiqueta.
Incluyo varios de estos controles en un formulario. En este formulario creo el evento ClickOpciones. Quiero que este evento se maneje desde cualquiera de los botones y se lo incluyo en el manejador de envento Click de los controles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es cuando pulso sobre el área del control que no contiene la imagen ni la etiqueta el evento me salta pero no así si pulso sobre la imagen y la etiqueta. Que debo hacer para que funcione en cualquier parte?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClickOpciones(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hola mundo, esto marcha...");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Panel extendido con una imagen y una etiqueta.
    /// </summary>
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(PanelOpciones), "PanelOpciones")]
    [Description("Panel extendido con una imagen y una etiqueta")]
    [Serializable]
    public class PanelOpciones : Panel
    {
        #region DESIGNER

        /// <summary>
        /// Variable del diseñador requerida.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Limpiar los recursos que se estén utilizando.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true si los recursos administrados se deben eliminar; false en caso contrario, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Código generado por el Diseñador de componentes

        /// <summary>
        /// Método necesario para admitir el Diseñador. No se puede modificar 
        /// el contenido del método con el editor de código.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(PanelOpciones));
            this.btnImagenPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lblTitulo = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnImagenPanel
            // 
            this.btnImagenPanel.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.btnImagenPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
            this.btnImagenPanel.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnImagenPanel.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;           
            this.btnImagenPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.btnImagenPanel.Name = "btnImagenPanel";
            this.btnImagenPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(16, 26);
            this.btnImagenPanel.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnImagenPanel.TabStop = false;
            this.btnImagenPanel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            // 
            // lblTitulo
            // 
            this.lblTitulo.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblTitulo.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblTitulo.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.lblTitulo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 5);
            this.lblTitulo.Name = "lblTitulo";
            this.lblTitulo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 14);
            this.lblTitulo.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // PanelOpciones
            // 
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnImagenPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblTitulo);
            this.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(26, 26);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.Button btnImagenPanel;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTitulo;


        #endregion

        #region Atributos        

        Color backColor = Color.White;

        #endregion

        #region Propiedades

        /// <summary>
        /// Devuelve o establece la descripción de la opción.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("_Ravisoft")]
        [Description("Devuelve o establece la descripción de la opción.")]
        public string _Opcion
        {
            get
            {
                return lblTitulo.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                lblTitulo.Text = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Devuelve o establece la imagen de la opción.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("_Ravisoft")]
        [Description("Devuelve o establece la imagen de la opción.")]
        public Image _OpcionImagen
        {
            get
            {
                return btnImagenPanel.Image;
            }
            set
            {
                btnImagenPanel.Image = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Devuelve o establece el Panel que mostrará.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("_Ravisoft")]
        [Description("Devuelve o establece el Panel que mostrará.")]
        public string _PanelForm { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Muestra un panel extendido con apariencia de formulario.
        /// </summary>
        public PanelOpciones()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _Opcion = "Opción...";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Liberar recursos.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Destructor de la clase.
        /// </summary>
        ~PanelOpciones()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Liberar recursos.
        /// Existe también el método Dispose(), tiene el mismo efecto.
        /// </summary>
        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose();
        }


        #endregion              

    }
```

Comment: No te sirve agregarle el mismo evento a cada subcontrol dentro del control principal? Crea un metodo llamado `SetOnClickListener` cuyo parametro sea un delegado con la firma requerida por el control y asignale ese parametro a cada elemento en el control.

Comment: @NaCl no entiendo bien lo que me dices. Pero creo que tiene que ver con la ayuda que me ha proporcionado Alberto Población en MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e9dba49e-30df-4141-92b7-ce5da693ec4c/lanzar-el-evento-click-de-un-usercontrol-pulsando-cualquier-control-del-mismo?forum=vcses

Comment: Si, es practicamente lo mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incluyo la solución que me dieron en MSDN para que conste la pregunta como resuelta:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e9dba49e-30df-4141-92b7-ce5da693ec4c/lanzar-el-evento-click-de-un-usercontrol-pulsando-cualquier-control-del-mismo?forum=vcses